# Junit - Should you create a db connection at beforeclass or before?

Tags: java, testing, junit

When doing integration tests it is often the case that you need to connect to a database and do some changes.

Should this be done in @BeforeClass or @Before in junit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `@BeforeClass` to set up a database connection.  The [Javadocs for `@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) indicate that `@BeforeClass` is better for setting up expensive resources such as database connections.

> Sometimes several tests need to share computationally expensive setup (like logging into a database). While this can compromise the independence of tests, sometimes it is a necessary optimization. Annotating a public static void no-arg method with @BeforeClass causes it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class.

If you use `@Before`, then a new `Connection` will be created for every `@Test` method, which sounds undesirable for just about all use cases.

Use `@BeforeClass` to set up your database connection.  Also use `@AfterClass` to close your connection.

Answer (score 0):

The code marked @Before is executed before each test, while @BeforeClass runs once before the entire test fixture. If your test class has ten tests, @Before code will be executed ten times, but @BeforeClass will be executed only once.

So to answer your question, you should be using @BeforeClass assuming all your test cases shares same db connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend the test methods to all use the same `Connection` then you should obtain it in a `@BeforeClass` method.  If you want each test method to use its own `Connection` then you should obtain it in a `@Before` method.  The latter better isolates your tests from each other, but there could be cases where the former is more appropriate.